# How to manage status bar color?

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar

I am android beginner , I want to create `status bar` as same as `Toolbar` and when `DrawerLayout` is opened `statusBar` again change as same as `DrawerLayout` ,how to solve this problem . I have already set in style  `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ed9797"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#e62e2e"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:background="#46dfcd"
        android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Drawer page"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change status bar color use `setStatusBarColor(int color).`

Working snippet of code:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom color for the status bar, use the `android:statusBarColor`  attribute on your application theme under styles.xml like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your status bar here. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/red</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: But if i created another Activity with different toolbar

Comment: This setting will affect all your activities on the application

Comment: But second toolbar is different color

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.your_color));
            }
           setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

                   //Your implementation
     }
```

Comment: And, could you please tell me how to manage the color of status bar when drawer is opened. The color of the drawer is different then the main screen.